# Replace 0 in one data set with values from another

Tags: r, dataset, subset

I have data that has produced `0` for the `User` `Rating` when the regression fails to converge.

I want to replace these `0` with the `User` `Mean` value that's in a different matrix.

I have the following code that does it, but it inefficient. Anyone have a more efficient eloquent way to code this problem?

```
pred <- data.frame(1:8, c(1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0), c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5))
names(pred) <- c("ID", "Rating", "User")
usermean <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(3,3,4,9,7))
names(usermean) <- c("User", "Mean")
temp <- subset(pred, pred$Rating ==0)
temp2 <- subset(pred, !pred$Rating == 0)
temp3 <- subset(usermean, User %in% temp$User)
temp4 <- join(temp, temp3, by = "User", type = "left")
temp4[,2] <- temp4[,4]
temp4 <- temp4[,1:3]
names(temp4) <- c("ID", "Rating", "User")
pred <- rbind(temp2, temp4)
temp <- NA; temp2 <- NA; temp3 <- NA; temp4 <- NA
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pred$Rating[pred$Rating == 0 ]  <-  usermean$Mean[pred$User[pred$Rating == 0 ] ]

#> pred
#  ID Rating User
#1  1      1    1
#2  2      2    1
#3  3      3    2
#4  4      4    2
#5  5      5    3
#6  6      9    4
#7  7      9    4
#8  8      7    5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
transform(pred, Rating = Rating + 
                       (Rating == 0) * usermean$Mean[match(User, usermean$User)])

  ID Rating User
1  1      1    1
2  2      2    1
3  3      3    2
4  4      4    2
5  5      5    3
6  6      9    4
7  7      9    4
8  8      7    5
```